# Как перевести &КЛАСС::МЕТОД в FName?

Tags: c++, делегаты, unreal-engine, type-conversion

Для привязки к делегату(delegate) метода(puskCode) - ему требуется передать имя метода в **формате текста** (FName):

```
class Simple : public AActor
{
private:
    FTimerDelegate delegate;
    
private:
    void BeginPlay()
    {
        delegate.BindUFunction(this, "puskCode");
    }
    
    void puskCode()
    {
        //реализация
    }
}
```

Возможно ли **получить имя** этого **метода**(puskCode) **в виде текста**(FName) **с помощью указания этого метода в формате &КЛАСС::МЕТОД** в какой - нибудь функции/макросе?

```
&Simple::puskCode
```

Для того что бы не иметь дело с обычным текстом (если я поменяю имя метода или вообще его удалю, то проект будет с написанием имени этого метода в виде строки - успешно компилиться и вылетать при запуске; для того что бы такого не было (что бы ошибка отсутствия переданного метода выявлялась на этапе компиляции) мне и нужно это сделать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишем макрос, который проверят доступность метода и потом возвращает его имя :

```c
# define MethodName( C , M ) ( ( & C :: M ) ? ( # M ) : "" )
```

`MethodName ( Simple , puskCode )` вернёт строку `"puskCode"` если этот метод существует и будут права доступа к нему.

Comment: Это похоже на еще один ответ, не имеющий отношения к формированию метаданных unreal-engine.